# Change deafult shortcut in Chrome from CTRL+1-8 to ALT+1-8

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

There is a popular shortcut in chrome: Pressing CTRL and any number 1 through 8 moves to the corresponding tab in your tab bar. I would like to use ALT instead of CTRL for this shortcut?

My question is: how to change it

Comment: You can try this? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortkeys-custom-keyboard/logpjaacgmcbpdkdchjiaagddngobkck

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a free solution.

Comment: You may have to create a macro using AutoHotKey. It can help you create customized keyboard shortcuts. Here is an example of similar Chrome shortcuts in AutoHotKey. (https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=19844)

Answer (score -1):

AutoHotKey script :

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe chrome.exe
!1::SwitchTab(1)
!2::SwitchTab(2)
!3::SwitchTab(3)
!4::SwitchTab(4)
!5::SwitchTab(5)
!6::SwitchTab(6)
!7::SwitchTab(7)
!8::SwitchTab(8)
#IfWinActive

SwitchTab(number) {
    SendInput ^%number%
}
```